# mongo db virtual get function how to return document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

details:mongodb,mongoose,nodejs
example :

```
 schema.virtual(''name').get(function() => {
 return this.anything;
 })
```

how the `this` key work to point document?
    Is `get` method return document?

Answer (score 0):

1. Might be a typo in the post but your string starts with two quotes.
2. You are mixing up the syntax for regular functions and arrow functions.

Do this:

```
schema.virtual('name').get(function() {
  return this.anything;
});
```

You cannot use an arrow function in this situation anyway since arrow functions do not allow the rebinding of the `this` context.